# How do I change the track object of an Edit Object actuator?

Tags: python, game-engine, workflow, logic-bricks

I wrote a script to change an Edit Object actuator track object based on which object it is near.

Here is the script, pretty much straight off the template:

```
import bge

def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    sens = cont.sensors['NearBad']
    actu = cont.actuators['Attack']

    if sens.positive:
        actu.track_object = sens.hitObject
        cont.activate(actu)

    else:
        cont.deactivate(actu)

main()
```

The `actu.track_object = sens.hitObject` is the line in question.
I wrote that based on what I think it should be, but what is the right syntax? How do I really do that?

Disclaimer: Although I work with BGE all the time, I have no coding experience at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit Object Actuator

The way you change an Edit Object actuator's object to track is with *[object](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bge.types.KX_TrackToActuator.html#bge.types.KX_TrackToActuator.object)*.
Here is what the if statement section of your code looks like.

```
if sens.positive:
    actu.object = sens.hitObject
    cont.activate(actu)
```

---

#### Steering Actuator

The way you change the Steering Actuator's object to track is with *[target](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bge.types.KX_SteeringActuator.html#bge.types.KX_SteeringActuator.target)*.
Here is what the if statement section of your code looks like.

```
if sens.positive:
    actu.target = sens.hitObject
    cont.activate(actu)
```

---

<sub>I initially thought you were using a different actuator (Steering) that is why both methods are listed.</sub>